# Adding multiple users at a time in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have created a joomla component where we can upload the csv file which contain the user name and email of many users.I have written query for inserting the data to the jos_users table.The password in auto generated and i have encrypted the password using 
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword("blabla", $salt);
I haven't inserted anything in the activation field.
But due to some reasons I cannot login using the username and the password.Should I do any thing else for this ?

Comment: check the Database table for the users and see if there is any difference in the format of your created users from the component and user created from the User Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Brent for your time.I have found the answer and is explained below.

For creating new user accounts by script you need to execute three queries.
1)
insert into `jos_users` (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`gid`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`) values (NULL,'name','username','email','password','Registered','0','0','18','date','date2')

2)
insert into `jos_core_acl_aro` (`id`,`section_value`,`value`,`name`) values (NULL, 'users', '(insertid of the above query)', 'name')

3)
insert into `jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map` (`group_id`,`section_value`,`aro_id`) values (18, '', '(insertid of the above query)')

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a user to be able to log in -

1. activation field must be blank
2. user must be enabled
3. user must be a member of a group

Comment: I'm using Joomla 1.5.As you said I have made the activation field blank and 0 is entered in the block field.Now what should be the value entered in the field gid ? I'm a bit confused on this.

Comment: I used this for gid $authorize =& JFactory::getACL(); $usersConfig = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' ); $newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' ); $gid=$authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ); and now while trying to login I'm getting the error "E_NOLOGIN_ACCESS"
why is it like this ? can any one help me on this !!

Comment: @nidhin about 0.5% of my joomla registering users get the stupid E_NOLOGIN_ACCESS error, so about 1 in every 200 users, I don't know how to fix, so I know its a bug in Joomla somewhere.